# When a variable change in a C# console application, the connection automatically change

Tags: c#, design-patterns, console-application, observer-pattern, strategy-pattern

Consider:

```
Console.WriteLine("Set firstValue");
decimal first = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
```

first variable

```
Console.WriteLine("Set Changeable Value");
decimal changeable = first + 5;
```

The second value depends on the first value:

```
Console.WriteLine("Set firstValue again");
first = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
```

When changing the first value, change automatically changeable value.
But I want to use the observer and strategy design pattern and really I mess up.

Comment: There's a lib available: https://github.com/dotnet/reactive - you'll find more blogs if you search for RxJS (the Javascript flavor)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an example of the [observer pattern in C# on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Observer_pattern):

```
public class Payload
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class Subject : IObservable<Payload>
{
    public IList<IObserver<Payload>> Observers { get; set; }

    public Subject()
    {
        Observers = new List<IObserver<Payload>>();
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<Payload> observer)
    {
        if (!Observers.Contains(observer))
        {
            Observers.Add(observer);
        }
        return new Unsubscriber(Observers, observer);
    }

    public void SendMessage(string message)
    {
        foreach (var observer in Observers)
        {
            observer.OnNext(new Payload { Message = message });
        }
    }
}

public class Unsubscriber : IDisposable
{
    private IObserver<Payload> observer;
    private IList<IObserver<Payload>> observers;
    public Unsubscriber(IList<IObserver<Payload>> observers, IObserver<Payload> observer)
    {
        this.observers = observers;
        this.observer = observer;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (observer != null && observers.Contains(observer))
        {
            observers.Remove(observer);
        }
    }
}

public class Observer : IObserver<Payload>
{
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public void OnCompleted()
    {
    }

    public void OnError(Exception error)
    {
    }

    public void OnNext(Payload value)
    {
        Message = value.Message;
    }

    public IDisposable Register(Subject subject)
    {
        return subject.Subscribe(this);
    }
}
```

Below is a test of the above code in action.

```
private void TestObserver()
{
    var subjectState1 = "Initial Update";
    var subjectState2 = "Second Update";
    var subjectState3 = "Last Update";

    var subject = new Subject();

    subject.SendMessage(subjectState1);

    Log("Updated subject to '" + subjectState1 + "'");

    var observer1 = new Observer.Observer();
    var observer2 = new Observer.Observer();

    var ob1Unobserve = subject.Subscribe(observer1);
    var ob2Unobserve = subject.Subscribe(observer2);

    Log("Ob1 val: " + observer1.Message);
    Log("Ob2 val: " + observer2.Message);

    subject.SendMessage(subjectState2);

    Log("Updated subject to '" + subjectState2 + "'");
    Log("Ob1 val: " + observer1.Message);
    Log("Ob2 val: " + observer2.Message);

    ob1Unobserve.Dispose();
    ob2Unobserve.Dispose();

    subject.SendMessage(subjectState3);

    Log("Updated subject to '" + subjectState3 + "'");
    Log("Ob1 val: " + observer1.Message);
    Log("Ob2 val: " + observer2.Message);
}
```

I noticed that the initial state is not sent to the observer on subscribe, which if you need it, can be implemented as such.

Inside the Subject class, I added the following:

I added a property for CurrentState:

```
public string CurrentState { get { return currentState; } }
private string currentState = null;
```

Inside of SendMessage I cache the current state:

```
currentState = message;
```

Inside Subscribe, I push the current state to the subscribing observable:

```
observer.OnNext(new Payload { Message = currentState });
```

Comment: That's okay. I did it. But I want to choise strategy. For example x=5 FirstObserver x+5 SecondObserver x*5 . When I change x how can show observer's value

Comment: @mach I updated my answer using the observable pattern example found on wikipedia